# Augmented reality in Android for Positioning Map Overlays on Camera View

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview, android-camera, augmented-reality

I am looking for AR SDK in android which helps me in positioning Map overlays/objects on Camera view based on GPS.
This is what I am trying to do in my app:
  **when the device is held straight up in a direction, corresponding map overlays should display on the Camera view along with a compass at top showing the directions.**
Hope I am clear enough! Looking for your suggestions. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few choices when it comes to AR

QCAR - Qualcomm Augmented Reality SDK - https://ar.qualcomm.com/qdevnet/sdk (Android & iOS)  ARToolKit -http://sourceforge.net/projects/... (Supports many devices)

popcode - http://www.popcode.info/demos (Supports Android and iPhone)
ARmsk -http://armsk.org/  SATCH - http://satch.jp/

But they might not be able to help you directly in placing map objects, you will have to handle your map stuff all by yourself, the sdk's will help you in turning the stuff into AR once they are ready to be pushed on camera view.